# Is there an Optimized Norm-Conserving Vanderbilt (ONCV) pseudopotential of $\rm Eu$ atom?

Tags: condensed-matter, atomic-physics, orbitals, density-functional-theory

I'm currently finding an Optimized Norm-Conserving Vanderbilt (ONCV) pseudopotential of [$\rm Eu$ atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium) which has a localized $f$-orbital.

But no matter how much I search in online, I can't find that.

In "http://www.quantum-simulation.org/potentials/sg15_oncv/upf/", other atoms have a ONCV pseudopotential, some of rare earth elements such as "Eu, Lanthanides" don't have one.

So, I request your help.
Does anyone have it? If so, please share.

Comment: Consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE. I guess the chances to get a good answer is much higher there.

Comment: Thanks!!~ Tobais Funke